# Magento Commands Not working

Tags: command-line, command

Any one can help will be highly appriciated, i'm running `magento 2.2.6`

> Deprecated Functionality: The each() function is deprecated. This
>   message will be suppressed on further calls in
>   /home/cellbezc/public_html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php
>   on line 81

[image]

Comment: This version isn't compatible with php7.2 guess it would be the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks alot for all supporters..

i got fixed.. by changing the PHP CLI Version to 7.0 .
you can check it by your self in command line `php -v` the PHP CLI Version must be 7.0 too.

Answer (score 0):

**`each()` function is deprecated in `php 7.2` so change this function to `foreach()`**

> In This File **vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php line no :- 81**

Change

```
  while (list($name, $value) = each($options)) {
        $this->setOption($name, $value);
    }
```

To

```
 foreach ($options as $name => $value){
        $this->setOption($name, $value);
    }
```

Comment: where you have to changes?

Comment: vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php line no :- 81

Comment: Please mention on the post

Comment: Check Updated Answer...!!!

Comment: NEVER EVER change files in vendor

Comment: but now error is 
-bash: bin/magento: Permission denied

Comment: to give permission this file